# Grid with auto adapting

Tags: html, css

I want to code a grid inside a div. The thumbnails to be used is is 150x150 px. Also need place for a small title and a excerpt. Was thinking building this into a Wordpress template later.

I have tried flex-box and css grid and all that. But with no luck.

```
<div class="container">

<div class="box">
</div>

<div class="box">
</div>

<div class="box">
</div>

<div class="box">
</div>

<div class="box">
</div>

<div class="box">
</div>

<div class="box">
</div>

<div class="box">
</div>

<div class="box">
</div>

<div class="box">
</div>

<div class="box">
</div>

</div>
```

I was looking to line the inner divs in a row that flexes then the width gets smaller like word wrap. It must line up with equal space all around the inner divs and wrap as the width gets smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Add this css it will work

```
   .container {
        display: flex;
        margin: auto;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .container .box{
      width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background: #ccc;
        margin: 5px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: flex-end;
        justify-content: center;
        border: 2px solid #000;
    }
```